# How to make magento WYSIWYG styles work

Tags: admin, cms, ce-1.8.1.0, css

I am looking for information about how i should be do by to wysiwyg Magento Styles editor work´s.
due that from default, this function is not available.

Comment: goto adminpanel `system->configuration->general->content management` Enable the **WYSIWYG** Editior

Comment: Thanks, But i am looking for the solutions for able the ****Styles Editor**** the WYSIWYG is working fine, just the Styles editor by default is not possible to upload or add new fonts.

Regards

Comment: this will not provide by magento you have to set the css for your custom block via css and add font via css.